# Execute a stored procedure in another database with params

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I need to get the column names of a table that's located in another database. The following script works for the active database but I need to run it against another database in the same server instance:

```
SELECT @ColumnList = 
    CASE
        WHEN @ColumnList IS NULL THEN name
        WHEN @ColumnList IS NOT NULL THEN @ColumnList + ',' + name
    END
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = Object_Id(@TableName);
```

Here's the issue... the database isn't known at compile time. Its passed into a stored procedure at runtime. So I see no alternative but to use dynamic sql. In the past I've tried using `Use [DBName]` in a dynamic sql script but always ran into problems until I realized I could do this:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT Foo FROM Bar'
SET @sp_executesql = quotename(@DatabaseName) + '..sp_executesql'
EXECUTE @sp_executesql @SQL
```

But I'm having difficulty figuring out how to do this with the script I mentioned above. My first attempt looked like:

```
-- @DatabaseName and @TableName are parameters of the 
-- stored procedure containing this script

DECLARE @ColumnList nvarchar(max),
        @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @sp_executesql nvarchar(max) = quotename(@DatabaseName) + '..sp_executesql';
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT @ColumnList = 
    CASE
        WHEN @ColumnList IS NULL THEN name
        WHEN @ColumnList IS NOT NULL THEN @ColumnList + '','' + name
    END
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = Object_Id(@TableName);'

EXECUTE @sp_executesql @SQL,
        N'@ColumnList = nvarchar(max) OUT, @TableName = sysname',
        @ColumnList, @TableName
```

But when it runs it doesn't interpret `@ColumnList` as a valid variable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you picked up that syntax, but here is how I would do it:

```
-- I assume these are parameters, so declaring them separately:
DECLARE 
    @DatabaseName SYSNAME = N'db_name',
    @TableName SYSNAME = N'table_name';

DECLARE 
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @columnList NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + '','', '''') 
    + c.name
    FROM [$db$].sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN [$db$].sys.tables AS o
    ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    WHERE o.name = @TableName;';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '$db$', @DatabaseName);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@ColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT, @TableName SYSNAME',
    @ColumnList OUTPUT, @TableName;

SELECT @ColumnList
```

Comment: Which syntax are you referring to?

Comment: `EXEC @sp_executesql @sql` - I assume you meant to be calling `EXEC sp_executesql @sql` in some way.

Comment: `EXEC @sp_executesql @sql` uses nested dynamic sql to call `sp_executesql` against `@DatabaseName`. Picked it up from [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Common_cases)

Comment: Just very weird to call the variable `@sp_executesql` and use it exactly in a place where the stored procedure `sp_executesql` would be expected. Nested dynamic SQL doesn't seem to be required here... did you try my code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `=` signs from the @*params* argument and add `OUT` or `OUTPUT` after the  *@ColumnList* argument.

**Correct:**

```
EXECUTE @sp_executesql @SQL,
        N'@ColumnList nvarchar(max) OUT, @TableName sysname',
        @ColumnList OUT, @TableName
```

**Incorrect:**

```
EXECUTE @sp_executesql @SQL,
        N'@ColumnList = nvarchar(max) OUT, @TableName = sysname',
        @ColumnList, @TableName
```

Comment: Yea, I noticed that when I looked at Aaron's solution